# How to query application state in an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make an auto-complete react component. Currently I am using Github's user search API to query for users that match a given query string. The auto complete works fine most of the time. However, because I am making multiple AJAX calls simultaneously, sometimes the response handler for query 1 is fired *after* the response handler for query 2. For example:

1. User enters query string "alex"
2. JS fires 4 asynchronous AJAX queries for the strings "a", "al", "ale" and "alex".
3. Response handler for query "a" returns.
4. Response handler for query "al" returns.
5. Response handler for query "alex" returns.
6. Response handler for query "ale" returns.
7. User sees results for query "ale" rather than "alex" as expected.

Here is some code to demonstrate this: https://codepen.io/alexspurling/pen/gOOWNpa?editors=0010

(note if you run this code that there is a 10 request per minute rate limit. If it stops working, wait a minute and try again)

[image: results]

[image: console]

As you can see from the console output, the results come back in the wrong order and the results displayed here are for the query "a", not "alex".

My attempted solution to this was to keep track of the most recently submitted query in my application state (see the `lastQuery` variable). However this fails because when the `receivedResults` function is called as I only have access to an old "closed-over" value rather than the actual current value of this part of the application state.

My question is, is it possible to read from actual current state from an asynchronous response handler? If not is this because it would break uni-directional data flow? How would you implement the desired behaviour in a way that maintains uni-directional data flow?

Note: I do NOT want to use a debounce or a delay. I also do not want to abort in flight requests. My question is more generally about data flow in React applications. The auto-complete example is simply a good way to demonstrate the question.

Comment: you can use React `refs` to inspect current value of the input and then set the result acordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to solve the issue is by using React `refs`, here's the modified codepen: https://codepen.io/rikin/pen/RwwVXeM?editors=0011

I modified your `Auto` component like below:

```
function Auto(props) {
  const inputref = React.useRef(null); // <-------------------------
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const queryNum = props.lastQuery + 1;
    search(value, queryNum, inputref); // <-------------------------
    props.setLastQuery(queryNum);   }, [value, inputref]);

  async function search(value, queryNum, inputref) {
    const url = 'https://api.github.com/search/users?q=' + value;
    const resp = await fetch(url)
    const json = await resp.json()
    if (json.items) {
      const users = json.items.map((item) => {
        return item.login;
      });
      inputref.current.value === value // <-----------------------
        && props.setResults({query: value, queryNum: queryNum, users: users});
    }   }

  return (
    <input value={value} ref={inputref} onChange={(e) => {setValue(e.target.value)}}></input>
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
  ) }
```

By doing this you are not cancelling inflight requests, you are not using debounce or a delay.
Rather once the response returns you are checking against input's current `value` and if it matches the `value` passed to it during the time of API request then it will perform `set` operation else it will discard.

There may be other ways (even more perform-ant or correct ones), this is my attempt of one such possible way to tackle the issue.